# mips-openwrt-linux-gcc: unrecognized option '-rpath-link'

Tags: c, gcc

when trying to build my application with toolchain-mips_gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1. I get an error in the link phase:

```
/home/hp/Desktop/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.3.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: warning: **ld-uClibc.so.0**, **needed by** /home/hp/Desktop/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.3.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/lib/libc.so, not found (**try using -rpath or -rpath-link**)
/home/hp/Desktop/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.3.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/lib/**libc.so**: undefined reference to `_dl_app_init_array'
/home/hp/Desktop/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.3.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/lib/libc.so: undefined reference to `_dl_loaded_modules'
/home/hp/Desktop/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.3.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/lib/libc.so: undefined reference to `_dl_app_fini_array'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

when trtying to add -rpath-link option

```
LDFLAGS += -rpath-link /home/hp/Desktop/staging_dir/target-mips_uClibc-0.9.30.1/root-brcmref/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0
```

I get the following error:
mips-openwrt-linux-gcc: unrecognized option '-rpath-link'

How could I fix this problem
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
LDFLAGS += --rpath-link /home/hp/Desktop/staging_dir/target-mips_uClibc-0.9.30.1/root-brcmref/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0
```

instead of

```
LDFLAGS += -rpath-link /home/hp/Desktop/staging_dir/target-mips_uClibc-0.9.30.1/root-brcmref/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `TARGET_LDFLAGS+=-rpath-link $(shell find $(STAGING_DIR) -name ld-uClibc.so.0)`
in your `package/PAK_NAME/Makefile`

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the soution at https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=25748, looks like that person ran into the same problem. did you by any chance move the toolchain?

Comment: --did you by any chance move the toolchain? -->yes

Comment: HI, Thanks for your help. I foud the solution for the problem: LDFLAGS += --rpath-link